# F# Basics: Folding 2 lists together into a string

Tags: f#, functional-programming

a little rusty from my Scheme days, I'd like to take 2 lists: one of numbers and one of strings, and fold them together into a single string where each pair is written like "{(ushort)5, "bla bla bla"},\n". I have most of it, i'm just not sure how to write the Fold properly:

```
let splitter = [|","|]
let indexes = 
  indexStr.Split(splitter, System.StringSplitOptions.None) |> Seq.toList 
let values = 
  valueStr.Split(splitter, System.StringSplitOptions.None) |> Seq.toList

let pairs = List.zip indexes values
printfn "%A" pairs

let result = pairs |> Seq.fold
    (fun acc a -> String.Format("{0}, \{(ushort){1}, \"{2}\"\}\n", 
                                acc, (List.nth a 0), (List.nth a 1)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your missing two things.  The initial state of the fold which is an empty string and you can't use list comprehension on tuples in F#.

```
let splitter = [|","|]
let indexes = 
    indexStr.Split(splitter, System.StringSplitOptions.None) |> Seq.toList 
let values = 
    valueStr.Split(splitter, System.StringSplitOptions.None) |> Seq.toList

let pairs = List.zip indexes values
printfn "%A" pairs

let result = 
    pairs 
    |> Seq.fold (fun acc (index, value) -> 
        String.Format("{0}{{(ushort){1}, \"{2}\"}},\n", acc, index, value)) ""
```

fold2 version

```
let result = 
    List.fold2 
        (fun acc index value -> 
            String.Format("{0}{{(ushort){1}, \"{2}\"}},\n", acc, index, value))
        "" 
        indexes 
        values
```

If you are concerned with speed you may want to use string builder since it doesn't create a new string every time you append.

```
let result = 
    List.fold2 
        (fun (sb:StringBuilder) index value -> 
            sb.AppendFormat("{{(ushort){0}, \"{1}\"}},\n", index, value)) 
        (StringBuilder()) 
        indexes 
        values
    |> string
```

Comment: of course it should be {{ and }} instead of \} and \{ in the format, i got that wrong :)

Answer (score 8):

Fold probably isn't the best method for this task. Its a lot easier to map and concat like this:

```
let l1 = "a,b,c,d,e".Split([|','|])
let l2 = "1,2,3,4,5".Split([|','|])
let pairs =
    Seq.zip l1 l2
    |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> sprintf "(ushort)%s, \"%s\"" x y)
    |> String.concat "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `List.fold2`.  For some reason the `List` module has a `fold2` member but `Seq` doesn't.  Then you can dispense with the `zip` entirely.

The types of your named variables and the type of the result you hope for are all implicit, so it's difficult to help, but if you are trying to accumulate a list of strings you might consider something along the lines of

```
let result = pairs |> Seq.fold
  (fun prev (l, r) -> 
          String.Format("{0}, \{(ushort){1}, \"{2}\"\}\n", prev, l, r) 
  "" pairs
```

My F#/Caml is very rusty so I may have the order of arguments wrong.  Also note your string formation is quadratic; in my own code I would go with something more along these lines:

```
let strings = 
   List.fold2 (fun ss l r -> 
                 String.format ("\{(ushort){0}, \"{1}\"\}\n", l, r) :: ss)
              [] indexes values

let result = String.concat ", " strings
```

This won't cost you quadratic time and it's a little easier to follow.  I've checked MSDN and believe I have the correct order of arguments on `fold2`.

Keep in mind I know Caml not F# and so I may have details or order of arguments wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
let strBuilder = new StringBuilder()
for (i,v) in Seq.zip indexes values do
     strBuilder.Append(String.Format("{{(ushort){0}, \"{1}\"}},\n", i,v))
     |> ignore
```

with F# sometimes is better go imperative...

Answer (score 0):

map2 or fold2 is the right way to go. Here's my take, using the `(||>)` operator:

```
let l1 = [| "a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e" |]
let l2 = [| "1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5" |]
let pairs = (l1, l2) ||> Seq.map2 (sprintf ("(ushort)%s, \"%s\""))
                      |> String.concat "\n"
```